# NSDictionary get value as string does not complain but lenngth or isEqualToString crashes

Tags: objective-c, json, nsdictionary

I got a Json like below as a response message.

```
data:{
    type = DATA;
    version = "4.51";
}
```

Which i process in below method, from the debugger it looks  like that version no is string.

```
-(void)processResponse:(NSDictionary *)responseDictionary{
    NSString *version = [responseDictionary valueForKey:@"version"];
    if([version isEqualToString:@"4.51"]){ //line 3
        NSLog(@"do something"); //crashes
    }
}
```

But line 3 crashes.
My question is why this line crashes? And what is the best way to handle this type of dictionary message?

Comment: Would you please share a crash log? It seems version is not an NSString, and doesn't respond to isEqualToString call.

Comment: Yes this is not string, but from NsLog I thought that it is a string.  my question is how can i realize that this is not a string. what is the best way to handle so, that it does not crash.

Comment: It seems that responseDictionary[@"version"] is not a string. It means that you should check your JSON schema first.

Comment: Maybe unrelated but never use `valueForKey` to get a single value from a dictionary unless you can explain why KVC is explicitly needed. Use – preferred – key subscription (`responseDictionary[@"version"]`) or `objectForKey` (`[responseDictionary objectForKey:@"version"]`)

Comment: @VladimirObrizan, if i had not the schema. what is the preventive code i should use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is data that originates outside your program, you must always check the types.

```
-(void)processResponse:(NSDictionary *)responseDictionary {
    id value = responseDictionary[@"version"];
    if ([value isKindOfClass: [NSString class]]) {
        NSString *version = value;
        if ([version isEqualToString: @"4.51"]) {
            NSLog(@"do something"); //crashes
        }
    }
}
```

If this is all you're going to do, then you can shorten it a little bit with `&&` short-circuiting, if you're careful.

```
-(void)processResponse:(NSDictionary *)responseDictionary {
    NSString *version = responseDictionary[@"version"];
    if ([version isKindOfClass: [NSString class]] 
        && [version isEqualToString: @"4.51"]) {

        NSLog(@"do something"); //crashes
    }
}
```

Just be very careful with this, because it means that `version` exists beyond this `if` block and may not be the correct type.

Again, if this is precisely your problem, you can also simplify it by using `isEqual:`, which applies to all `NSObject`:

```
-(void)processResponse:(NSDictionary *)responseDictionary {
    id version = responseDictionary[@"version"];
    if ([version isEqual: @"4.51"]) {
        NSLog(@"do something"); //crashes
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, The first approach looks like more robust to me. I can check string or number and then do the stuff.